# Реализация открытия карточки swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa, swiftui

Подскажите в каком направлении двигаться, чтобы реализовать данную сцену в storyboard Xcode 11.
[image: Карточка создания письмо]

Есть список, нужно, чтобы при нажатии на Item открывалась подробная информация в такой карточке. Информация подтягивается с сервера. Информация будет без возможности редактирования.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С iOS 13 это стандартное поведение при `present` контроллера. Поэтому просто создаете нужный контроллер, получаете данные и отображаете как нужно.